# How to combine Data in PCollection - Apache beam

Tags: java, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am looking for combining data in a PCollection

input is a CSV file

```
customer id,customer name,transction amount,transaction type  
cust123,ravi,100,D  
cust123,ravi,200,D  
cust234,Srini,200,C  
cust444,shaker,500,D  
cust123,ravi,100,C  
cust123,ravi,300,C
```

O/p should be

After reading a Textfile in to a collection of object, i want  to combine as the output shown.

```
cust123,ravi,300,D  
cust123,ravi,400,C  
cust234,Srini,200,C  
cust444,shaker,500,D
```

```java
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(
   PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create());

PCollection< Customer> pCollection =
   pipeline.apply("Read", TextIO.read().from("MyFile.csv"))
           .apply("splitData and store",
               ParDo.of(new TextTransform.SplitValues()))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right you need to sum the transaction amounts grouping by customerid+transaction type. In that case you need to, from high level perspective:

- assign the keys to the records:

  - you can use `WithKeys` `PTransform` for that, [see the doc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/WithKeys.html);
  - the key is up to you, for example you can combine the customer id with transaction type something like: `csvField[0] + "," + csvField[3]`
- group the records by the new key using `GroupByKey` `PTransform`, [see this doc](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#groupbykey);
- the output of the GBK will be collections of the records with the same key, so you will need to apply a `ParDo` that will accept such collection (all records belonging to the same customer and transaction type), sum up the amount, output the record with the sum;

Last two steps (GBK+ParDo) can probably be replaced by using a `Combine.perKey()` `PTransform`, which does the same thing but can be optimized by the runtime. See [this](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.html) and [this](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#combine) for more info.

You can also look into Beam SQL that would allow you to express the same logic in SQL. See [this doc](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/overview/) for Beam SQL overview. In this case you will need to add a `ParDo` that converts the CSV records to Beam Rows before applying the `SqlTransform`.